# Apply difference between two branches on a third branch

Tags: git

I have these branches:

- main
- feature-base (based on main)
- feature-foo (based on feature-base)

The branch "feature-base" contains a lot of commits which are not needed any more.

I want to create a new branch "only-foo" which contains the difference between "feature-base" and "feature-foo".

I thought about this solution

```
git checkout feature
git diff feature-foo > ~/tmp/foo.patch
git switch main
git switch -c only-foo
patch -p0 < ~/tmp/foo.patch
```

But this does not include binary files.

Is there a better way to apply the difference of two branches to a third branch?

It is fine to get the changes only. It is ok if commit-messages (and other meta-data) from "feature-foo" get lost.

Comment: I recommend looking at `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase`. I'll write up a more detailed answer later when I have more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the `only-foo` branch as a copy of `feature-foo`:

```
git branch only-foo feature-foo
```

Then use use `git rebase` with the `--onto` option and rebase it onto `main`:

```
git rebase --onto main feature-base only-foo
```

This makes `main` the new base, applying to it all commits from `only-foo` having `feature-base` as old base.

Note that you can skip creating the `only-foo` branch and rebase `feature-foo` directly if you don't need that branch anymore afterwards.

See also the section [Advanced rebase application](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) of the git tutorial for further details on rebasing.

Answer (score 3):

Applying a "patch" is always going to be tricky because git lacks the context of the parts that the patch is coming from (which it has when doing cherry-picking and such).

I would do it like this. Suppose the scenario is *I want to apply the result of `git diff A..B`  onto C*. I would do this:

```
git checkout -b temp B
git reset --soft A # put all differences between A and B in index ready to commit
git commit -m "Single commit for A..B"
git checkout C
git cherry-pick temp
```

That should do it.