# Apply only the changes from a new branch onto an older branch

Tags: git, git-branch, rebasing

I have 2 branches : `feature1` and `feature2` which are based on the `develop` branch. `feature1` is based on an older commit while `feature2` is more recent.

I want to get only the commits from `feature2` that are not in develop onto `feature1`.

I tried `git rebase --onto feature1 develop feature2` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357559/5959374), but I see that commits from develop are still getting applied onto `feature1`. What am I missing here?

Update : It turns out that the local `develop` branch was not up-to-date with the remote `develop` while `feature2` was based on a more recent commit on the remote `develop`. This is why the commits from the remote `develop` were getting rebased.

Comment: That command should be fine. What does yoru commit history graph look like?

Comment: "Update : It turns out that the local develop branch was not up-to-date with the remote develop. This is the reason why the command was not working earlier. This is working now." – so "not reproducible or caused by a typo". If you wanted to rebase on the remote develop, you should use `origin/develop`. I'm voting to close, the command (`rebase --onto feature1 develop feature2`) works just fine (as indicated by OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926098/apply-only-the-changes-from-a-new-branch-onto-an-older-branch/75926111?noredirect=1#comment133919350_75926111), `git rebase --onto A B C` always takes the commit range `B..C` (i.e. `^B C`)

That means it should target commits from `D` (excluded) up to `f2` HEAD (none of those commits should be from `develop`, reachable from `develop`):

```
          f2--f2 (feature2)
         /
--d--d--D--d (develop)
     \
      f1--f1 (feature1)

git rebase --onto feature1 develop feature2

--d--d--D--d (develop)
     \
      f1--f1 (feature1)
            \
             f2'--f2' (feature2)
```

> `feature1` was merged into `feature2` earlier without deleting the `feature1` branch.

So:

```
         f1--f1--f1--f1     (feature1)   
        /          \
       /        f2--f2--f2  (feature2)  
      /        /
--d--d--d--d--d             (develop)
```

However, the OP adds:

> My local `develop` branch was not up-to-date with the remote develop while the other branches were up-to-date.
> This is why the commits from the remote develop were getting rebased

So:

```bash
gi fetch
git switch feature1
git rebase --onto feature1 origin/develop feature2
```

Comment: OP's command would work with this commit graph just as fine, no need for `merge-base`. `git rebase --onto feature1 develop feature2` would only take rebase commits `f2` and `f3`

Comment: @knittl Intuitively, I thought it would have worked only if feature2 was based on develop HEAD, not on develop past commit.

Comment: `git rebase --onto A B C` always takes the commit range `B..C` (i.e. `^B C`). Which other range would make sense?

Comment: @knittl So the graph history must not be the one I described.

Comment: Somehow this does not work, I have the same issue as before

Comment: @Abhilash can you show the result of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`?

Comment: @VonC I am unable to share this info here, I had believed that the situation is as you described, but I guess this is not true. Could you please suggest what I can look for?

Comment: @Abhilash Check the nature of the commit you think are from `develop` after rebase: as knittl mentioned, none of the rebased commits should be from `develop`.

Comment: @Abhilash After seeing your edit, I tried a new Git history schema: would it represent your current situation?

Comment: @VonC Your new schema is accurate, but I found out the cause of the issue. My local `develop` branch was not up-to-date with the remote `develop` while the other branches were up-to-date. This is why the commits from the remote `develop` were getting rebased.

Comment: @Abhilash Good catch: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.